# Getting values from JSON using REST client

Tags: spring, rest

My api is working fine and I did get back JSON result when tested in POSTMAN. I have problem retrieving the JSON value through a controller using a REST client. I am using spring and hibernate.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewForm/{id}")
    public String viewForm(@Valid @PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String fooResourceUrl
            = "http://localhost:8080/api/delivery/searchDanceform/"+ id;

        System.out.println(fooResourceUrl);

        ResponseEntity<DanceApplicationForm> rateResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(fooResourceUrl,
                            HttpMethod.GET, null, DanceApplicationForm.class);
        DanceApplicationForm response = rateResponse.getBody();

        System.out.println(response);
        logger.info("result = {}", response);

        return VIEW_PATH + "dance-profile";

    }
```

I got this error,

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/intranet-web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at sg.com.ctc.intranet.web.training.controller.DanceController.viewDanceApplicationForm(DanceController.java:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I have also tried this way.

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(fooResourceUrl, String.class);
```

but is still not working.

Comment: Inside viewForm controller you are calling this url "http://localhost:8080/api/delivery/searchDanceform/"+ id; and in your answer section your controller name is viewDanceApplication which does not match with calling url that means controller name must match with searchDanceform

Comment: I can calling the API method in my rest controller using REST client. Thus, the API link and the controller name need not be the same i think.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `null` value in exchange method, actually in place of `null` you have to pass entity refrence.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
ResponseEntity<DanceApplicationForm> rateResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, DanceApplicationForm.class);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I still get the same error. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Can you share controller code of the calling url in exchange method, because error is" 404" which is basically for page not found or url path is incorrect.

Comment: I have post my controller in the answer section because I am not too sure where I should place it in. Please take a look. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I place it in the answer section because I am not too sure where I can reply with my code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/viewDanceApplication/{id}")
    public String viewDanceApplicationForm(@Valid @PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String fooResourceUrl
            = "http://localhost:8080/api/delivery/searchDanceform/"+ id;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<DanceApplicationForm> rateResponse = restTemplate.exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, DanceApplicationForm.class);

    logger.info("result = {}", rateResponse);



    model.addAttribute("showProfile",rateResponse);

 return VIEW_PATH + "dance-profile";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your handler controller of

```
http://localhost:8080/api/delivery/searchDanceform/

 @RequestMapping(value = "/searchDanceform/{id}")
    public String searchDanceform(@Valid @PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
          // do your code and return response




    }
```